# Chi-Squared Goodness of Fit Test for a Poisson Distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution

[image]

H0: It is a Poisson Distribution.

H1: It isn't a Poisson Distribution.

At the 5% significance level:

degrees of freedom: k - 2 = 6 - 2 = 4 so a critical value of 9.49

Now I need to find: total number of burglaries/total number of weeks.

In order to get the total number of burglaries I need to find the sum of the FX but I'm not sure about what to do for "more than 4" when x is the number of burglaries and and f is the number of weeks. So it's "more than 4" multiplied by 2.. do I take more than 4 as 5 or is there a way to find it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I noticed the $2.$ at the beginning. Does $1.$ give some additional informations ? Or has it nothing to do with $2.$ ?

Comment: No it's completely irrelevant to this question and is on a different topic altogether.

Comment: And the value of $\lambda$ is not known, it must be estimated, right ?